# React-Native: image resizeMode not working properly

Tags: react-native

I'm having issues trying to set `resizeMode: 'cover'` in `Image` component

This image summarizes my issue :

[image]

I'm testing it on **Android**, **RN 0.55.3** and this my sample code

```
<View style={{ width: 200, height: 200, backgroundColor: '#555' }}>
  <Image
    source={require('./bird.jpg')}
    style={{ alignSelf: 'stretch', flex: 1, resizeMode: 'cover' }}
  />
</View>
```

Also tried :

```
<View style={{ width: 200, height: 200, backgroundColor: '#555' }}>
      <Image
        source={require('./bird.jpg')}
        style={{ alignSelf: 'stretch', flex: 1 }}
        resizeMode='cover'
      />
</View>
```

But neither is working, so is there any way to get it work properly ?

Comment: try resizeMode as a props outside from style

Comment: @anilsidhu it has the same effect as resizeMode inside the style

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found that `resizeMode` doesn't work properly unless I set the `width` of the `Image`

I used `width: 'auto'` and everything worked well

the final code :

```
<View style={{ width: 200, height: 200, backgroundColor: '#555' }}>
  <Image
    source={require('./bird.jpg')}
    style={{ alignSelf: 'stretch', flex: 1, resizeMode: 'cover', width: 'auto' }}
  />
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

I define Image tag as below. resizeMode outside the style.

```
 <View style={{ width: 200, height: 200, backgroundColor: '#555' }}>
      <Image
        source={require('./bird.jpg')}
        style={{ alignSelf: 'stretch', flex: 1,width : 'auto'}}
        resizeMode={'cover'}
      />
 </View>
```

this works for me.

Comment: it has the same effect as inside the style .. doesn't work without setting the width